# MySQL - Convert single column into an array

Tags: mysql, arrays, mariadb

I have a column of data, e.g. as follows:

```
select league_id from leagues
```

This gives me a single column (`league_id`) and 100+ rows for that column.

I want to convert it into a single cell (1 row, 1 column) with the following structure:

```
[1001, 1002, 42022, 203412,  24252, etc..]
```

Essentially converting the rows into one big array.

There must be a way of doing it but can't see how.

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.

Comment: rftm: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/) function for that.

Usage is straightforward:

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1001 |
| 2 | 1002 |
| 3 | 42022 |
| 4 | 203412 |
| 5 | 24252 |

```
SELECT group_concat(val) 
  FROM tab
```

gives you

| group_concat(val) |
| --- |
| 1001,1002,42022,203412,24252 |

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f7c51f44c1ec8e6c7867a3c8921ff27d).

(Note: Before MariaDB 10.3.3 you cannot use the `LIMIT` clause with `GROUP_CONCAT`, in case you should need that).